# how to get current line number in Classic ASP code

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to find a way how to get the code line number in Classic ASP

```
<%
Response.Write "Hello world!<br>"
Response.Write getThisLineNumber() & "<br>"
Response.Write "Goodbye world."
%>
```

Expected output

```
Hello world.
3
Goodbye world.
```

`getThisLineNumber()` is a fictional function doing what I'm looking for.

I temporarily solved my problem by

```
<%
Response.Write "Hello world!<br>"
Response.Write "3<br>"
Response.Write "Goodbye world."
%>
```

but when i add a new line after "Hello world." (2nd line), then I manually must change

```
Response.Write "3<br>"
```

to

```
Response.Write "4<br>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP does not support such a feature, it's something like Reflection in `.NET`.
The closer thing you can do is get line number when an error happens in `Err` object, this way: `Err.Line`.

If you want to profile an `asp` page, maybe **ASP Profiler** can help you: [ASP Profiler](https://github.com/zbarutcu/asp-profiler)